# Have Google Analytics show a single number that is between two periods of time

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, how can I get a single number that is a change between two periods?

For example, I have a bounce rate in December that is **28%**. I have a bounce rate in Januaray that is **22%**.  How can I get a widget on the page to just show **-6%**.

Comment: If you downvote, it's common courtesy to leave a comment explaining why so the question can be improved. Thanks

Comment: Wasn't me :) I thought it was a fine question. I'll upvote to counter whoever did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is known as a "calculated metric", and currently there's no way to do this in Google Analytics (outside of the built-in calculated metrics like `ga:percentNewUsers`).

The best way to do this right now is to make two queries to the API and write some code that does the calculation yourself.

Since you mentioned having a widget on the page that displays this data, you might look into the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) to do the queries